# Ubuntu 14.04 wont shutdown or reboot

Tags: 14.04, shutdown

Have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on a Toshiba Satellite S50 with Windows 7.  Offnote: Was experiencing freezes with the proprietary nvidia driver so I switched to the Nouveau driver.

My ubuntu will not shut down or reboot.  I try typing

```
sudo reboot -h -q now
```

among other variations as well as shutdown but I get other outcomes:

1. It closes x and freezes at the terminal with a _
2. It closes x and I get a terminal:

   ```
   wait-for-state stop/waiting
   * Stopping rsync daemon rsync
   saned disabled; edit /etc/default/saned
   * speech-dispacher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispacher
   Stopping SpamAssassin Mail Filter Daemon: No /usr/bin/perl found running; none killed.
   spamd.
   ModemManager[828]: <info> ModemManager is shut down
   ModemManager[828]: <info> ModemManager (version 1.0.0) is starting...
   ModemManager[828]: <warn> Could not acquire the 'org.freedesktop.ModemManager1' service name
   ModemManager[828]: <info> ModemManager is shut down
   ModemManager[828]: <info> ModemManager (version 1.0.0) is starting...
   ModemManager[828]: <warn> Could not acquire the 'org.freedesktop.ModemManager1' service name
   ModemManager[828]: <info> ModemManager is shut down
   * Killing all remaining processes...
   * Will now switch to single-user mode
   ```

   root@laptop:~#

And I get a root prompt.

Side Notes: Using Gnome Desktop, lightdm

Why am I unable to shutdown or reboot?

Comment: Have you tried using ´sudo shutdown -h now´ and ´sudo shutdown -r 0´ (from another thread: http://superuser.com/questions/360544/ubuntu-shutdown-fail-killing-all-remaining-processes)

Comment: I experience the same in a VirtualBox machine. The only thing I did was install Ubuntu, then "sudo init 0".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Confirmed to be a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/1174272
The solution using `sudo shutdown -r 0` to reboot, and `sudo shutdown -h now` to shut down, worked around it. It seems to be getting some attention now.

Comment: How about using **sudo init 0** to shutdown and **sudo init 6** to restart?

Comment: I get this message when I use "Shutdown" from the GUI--it appears in the top right of the screen without a shell prompt. In this case, where I can't type `sudo shutdown`, what should I do?

Comment: sudo shutdown -r 0 to reboot did not work in 14.04 for me

Comment: none of the proposed solutions worked

Answer (score 5):

For others with this problem, I was experiencing the same thing. I didn't even have to try this (which was my "okay, i'll deal with it this way" option).

After a Google search I found another solution, which is to go into `/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services` and rename the file `org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.service` to anything else. I called mine `thisfilebreaksmycomputer.service`. I had [to `sudo`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) the [`mv`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/mv.1.html) command to do this.

Upon renaming I was able to successfully shut down and boot up without any issues!

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: Trying it. At work, so it may take a while before I reboot....

Comment: also didnt work in Ubuntu 14.04