# Can not log into Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, boot

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS along side Windows 7. I am trying to log into Ubuntu, but can't pass boot screen, doesn't matter how long I wait.

[image]

The problem started when I installed a series of software and tried to restart the system. The software were requirements of a course and are listed under title **Software available through apt-get** and **Software available through easy_install** in the following link:

http://faculty.washington.edu/rjl/uwhpsc-coursera/software_installation.html#apt-get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The problem caused because of `xdm`, technically I don't know what `xdm` affected, but uninstalling it through recovery mode solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Press escape on that screen, any error messages?
My suggestion would be to uninstall whatever packages seemed to break your system. Type [CTRL] + [ALT] + [F1] and login with your username and password. Use `sudo apt-get remove PACKAGE` to remove the files that broke your system.

Comment: I followed what you said but I did not see any error message. I took the snapshots and I am sharing them in Drive: [link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5UInL1OsMmQfndFUUhUNGt0M1ZxUEVEcEdaNHM1bUFJcDU3SVctV3hrV0k0eGZLZ1Rwa3c&usp=sharing). I can see a fail message when I tried to shutdown the system using command.

Comment: Hmm...ModemManager may be a problem, do you use modems? If not, remove that package and see what happens.

Comment: Sorry. but that did not helped.Regarding the 'ModemManager1', here is a similar issue: http://askubuntu.com/questions/462560/ubuntu-14-04-wont-shutdown-or-reboot

Comment: Try uninstalling the packages you installed before then.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help Zzzach, but I re-installed Ubuntu from bootable-USB. Thanks again.