# 15.10 - Ubuntu does not power off on shutdown

Tags: boot, grub2, power-management, shutdown, 15.10

I have been around the internet trying to find the answer and no solution given has worked.

I have disabled quiet and splash from `/etc/default/grub` so I can see the output. When shutting down, there are no errors, but the system halts on the line

```
[  OK  ] Reached target Shutdown.
```

Does this mean the system has finished all processes etc.? After this I have to power down by holding the power button. This was also a problem in 14.04. Is there anything I can do to get the computer to power down?

Comment: Have you tried using `sudo shutdown now`

Comment: That may not necessarily be the cure, David. It might be the very same thing as I had here: a __hardware__ issue. For instance, the culprit might be a dying resp. soon-to-die harddrive, which (due to its malfunction) is either "only" slowing down the whole system, or even blocking some internal processes. If this ever happened on my box, the first thing I would've done is check `/var/log/kern.log` and related logs. Come to think of it, `dmesg | grep Emask` might also come in handy.

Comment: @DavidCole "sudo shutdown now" gives the same results.

Comment: Maybe related to: http://askubuntu.com/questions/680212/ubuntu-wont-shutdown-or-freezes-at-splash-screen/680223#680223

Comment: I have this problem with 15.10 on an Intel NUC DE3815TYKH. A work-around appears to be disabling XHCI USB controllers in the BIOS...