# ubuntu 20.04 desktop does not shut down

Tags: 20.04, shutdown

I am running ubuntu 20.04 on an old HP desktop. it works really well except when I shut down (sudo poweroff), it is hung displaying an ubuntu logo. I tried to follow a few related threads but no luck.

I had run other flavors of linux on the same desktop in the past, for example proxmox and it used to shutdown properly.

Am I missing something?

References,

[Ubuntu 18.04 stuck at shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029068/ubuntu-18-04-stuck-at-shutdown)
[ubuntu won't shutdown or freezes at splash screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/680212/ubuntu-wont-shutdown-or-freezes-at-splash-screen)

Comment: Wait 35 minutes (for a hypothetical 30 minute timeout), then reboot and do `sudo journalctl -b -1 -xe` to see the end of the log of the previous boot. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: @waltinator, Do you mean, I should shutdown and wait for 35 mins and then manually reboot? I am trying to understand on what state should I wait for 35 mins?

Comment: Before you sleep, `sudo shutdown -r now`. When you awaken, login and `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` to show the end of the previous boot's logs. Some of `shutdown`'s tasks set a 30 minute timeout, in case they hang, then hang (fail to terminate). In my Ubuntu 16.04, it had to do with encrypted swap. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on my HP Victus laptop and was mucking around with acpi kernel parameters and all sorts of things but in the end what fixed it was manually installing the Nvidia drivers.  They weren't showing up under additional drivers for me so I had to run "sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-440".  I additionally had to adjust the priority of my hidden wireless network to keep it connecting automatically (I mention this because they were both tricky problems with the HP I had).  Your mileage may vary you may need a different driver but it's either X Server not shutting down or an acpi kernel parameter that needs to be set.  There are other pages about kernel parameters I'll link you one here:  https://discovery.endeavouros.com/acpi-kernel-parameters/acpi-kernel-parameters-and-how-to-choose-them/2021/03/